# What is the difference between a skew-symmetric and an antisymmetric tensor?

Tags: definition, tensor-calculus

What is the difference between a skew-symmetric and an anti-symmetric tensor?
If they represent the same tensor, then why use different labeling.

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between them.

Comment: I agree with Hunter, it's the same thing.

Comment: Agree there's no difference.  Physicists tend to favor the term "antisymmetric" and mathematicians tend to favor the term "skew-symmetric" in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

I) Many English words come in both a Greek and a Latin version. The prefix [*anti-*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anti-) is from Greek and the prefix [*skew-*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skew) is from French.

Most authors would define an [*anti-symmetric*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_tensor) and a [*skew-symmetric*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) (possibly higher-order) tensor as precisely the same thing.

II) However, in the context of [supernumber-valued](http://planetmath.org/supernumber) tensors, some authors define a second-order anti-symmetric tensor/matrix as

$$\tag{A} A_{ab}=(-1)^{(|a|+1)(|b|+1)}A_{ba},$$

while a second-order skew-symmetric tensor/matrix obeys

$$\tag{S} S_{ab}=-(-1)^{|a||b|}S_{ba},$$

cf. Ref. 1. Here $|a|$ denotes the Grassmann-parity of the coordinate index $a$.

References:

1. D. Leites, *Seminar on supersymmetry. Vol. 1. Algebra and Calculus,* 2006.